# Google Play - Multiple APK in Beta Testing

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Google Play has changed APK menu to Version Manager, or something like that (my Store is in spanish).

Now i've read how to upload multiple APKs to production, but what if I want to upload multiple APK (x86 and armv7) for BETA testing? I'm using ionic with Crosswalk Project and it generates 2 apks.

In previous version you had to enable advanced mode, but I don't see advanced mode in this Version Manager.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you for your time!